# Upgrade MySQL to 5.1 on Ubuntu Plesk VPS

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, vps

Is it possible to upgrade MySQL to 5.1 on a VPS running Ubuntu 10.04, without breaking Plesk?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes  . Plesk  using table on mysql server    you have to make first export  or dump  on mysql server for secure reason  and for  backup reason if something  is broken. Then    just use apt-get update & apt-get upgrade . I thing all will be OK all new version  can support all old version and etc.